# Flutter error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

So I started learning dart and flutter and during watching some course I ran into this error. Have something been changed in flutter, why is it not working? Also I'm sorry if I didn't attach something needed, I'm new in this world. Thanks!

> error part

```
Column (
    children: [

  Pytanie(
    pytania[_indekspytan]['tekstPytan'],
  ),
```

> and here is the whole column

```
Column(

children: [

  Pytanie(
    pytania[_indekspytan]['tekstPytan'], 
  ),

  ...(pytania[_indekspytan]['odpowiedzi'] as List<String> ).map((odpowiedz)   { //kropki zapobiegaja tworzeniu 2 listy, podmienia wartosci

    return Odpowiedz(_odpowiedzi,  odpowiedz);

  }).toList()


],



),
```

Comment: Please, pay attention to the format of the code. Use formatting options available in StackOverflow editor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about using toString()

```
Pytanie(
    pytania[_indekspytan]['tekstPytan']?.toString() ?? ''
),
```